# std::vector::emplace_back with lvalue expression

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, emplace

Does it ever make practical sense to use `emplace_back` with lvalue of some struct `S`:

like this:

```
std::vector<S> v;
auto s = S(/*...*/);
v.emplace_back(s);
```

Instead of just:

```
v.emplace_back(/* S constructor arguments */);
```

or is it just plain misuse of `emplace_back`, that only happen to work because `const S&` (and thus a copy constructor) is legitimate instantiation for `Args... args` inside `emplace_back`, and it is not forbidden explicitely?

Comment: Do you need `s` later on in the code?  If not, it is a misuse.

Comment: Wouldn't you do: `v.emplace_back(std::move(s));` otherwise you might as well use `push_back`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you already said, passing `const S&` would just invoke the copy constructor.

Unless you intend to use `s` in some way before passing it to `emplace_back`, it is therefore not necessarily wise.

However, if the code to create `s` was, for instance, exceptionally long, it could improve readability to put it and the code for `emplace_back` on separate lines. Compilers are extremely good at optimizing such cases and will probably generate the same code anyways (if the copy constructor is default). Basic example: https://godbolt.org/z/D1FClE

If it improves readability or maintainability do it, otherwise there’s no value in it.

Comment: `std::move(s)` might allow to use move constructor though to avoid copy.

Comment: @Jarod42 True. But std::move converts `s` to an "xvalue" and the question is about lvalues.

Comment: "if the copy constructor is default". I was trying at first to user-define copy constructor with some print-out to cout to see if it is called, but I guess that actually influenced the test by calling it. However, the emplace_back with argument pack only for the actual constructor arguments does not call copy-constructor, even if it is user-defined.

Comment: @Student4K Your last sentence describes the expected behavior. Adding a print statement will certainly prevent the compiler from optimizing the copy constructor away.

Answer (score 1):

If `s` is not needed later in the code, then it is a misuse of the `emplace_back()` function. This is because you are invoking the copy constructor of the `S` class instead of passing the arguments to the `emplace_back()` which will use the correct constructor from `S`.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct S
{
    S()          {std::cout<< "     default ctor" <<std::endl;}
    S(int)       {std::cout<< "     user-def ctor" <<std::endl;}
    S(const S &) {std::cout<< "     copy ctor" <<std::endl;}
    S(S &&)      {std::cout<< "     move ctor" <<std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<S> v;
    v.reserve(5);

    std::cout<< "auto calls: " <<std::endl;
    auto s = S();
    std::cout<<std::endl;

    std::cout<< "emplace_back( s ) calls: " <<std::endl;
    v.emplace_back(s);
    std::cout<<std::endl;

    std::cout<< "emplace_back( std::move(s) ) calls: " <<std::endl;
    v.emplace_back(std::move(s));
    std::cout<<std::endl;

    std::cout<< "emplace_back( S{} ) calls: " <<std::endl;
    v.emplace_back(S{});
    std::cout<<std::endl;

    std::cout<< "emplace_back( ) calls: " <<std::endl;
    v.emplace_back();
    std::cout<<std::endl;

    std::cout<< "emplace_back( 2 ) calls: " <<std::endl;
    v.emplace_back(2);
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

The results are:

```
auto calls: 
     default ctor

emplace_back( s ) calls: 
     copy ctor

emplace_back( std::move(s) ) calls: 
     move ctor

emplace_back( S{} ) calls: 
     default ctor
     move ctor

emplace_back( ) calls: 
     default ctor

emplace_back( 2 ) calls: 
     user-def ctor
```

The reserve is used to allocate space for 5 `S`s. Without reserving the space, the outputs would include additional calls to the copy ctors from the vector.

When you just pass the arguments to the constructor of `S` (in this case, nothing), the `emplace_back()` creates an S object using the default ctor directly inside the vector.

Btw, see the [example in godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/dDFoGH) which is your friend in these cases to see exactly what happens in the background.